# Embedded cobertura code coverage status (MarkDown)

Tags: github, jenkins, code-coverage, cobertura

I have use pycov, pytest and pycobertura to generate an xml published on jenkins using the cobertura plug-in. I am using the "Embedded Build Status" plug-in to get the build status icon for GitHub. However, I'm unsure how to extract an embedded icon for code coverage.

Any advise is really welcome

Cheers